# va_list in C++ 64 Bits

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, 64-bit, variadic-functions

I work with VS2500 and now I want to compile my application under x64 bits but the compiler show me an error:

```
error C3861: '_INTSIZEOF': identifier was not found
```

What can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to include `<stdarg.h>` to use `va_list`.

That will bring in the necessary definition for `_INTSIZEOF`.

---

Actually, on closer look - when compiling for x64 (or amd64) VS 2005 doesn't seem to use `_INTSIZE` in its `stdarg.h` implementation.  What line of code is generating the error, and are you sure you have you project configured correctly for an x64 build?

I'd especially look at include files paths (setting the `/showIncludes` option might point out problems with incorrect headers being pulled in). Your build should pick up `stdarg.h` and `vadefs.h` from:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include
```

Comment: When I compile with Win32 it works fine, but when I do with x64, the compiler show me: >.\Errores.cpp(337) : error C3861: '_INTSIZEOF': identifier was not found
1>.\Errores.cpp(337) : error C4235: is nonstandard extension used: the keyword '__asm​​' is not supported on this architecture
1>.\Errores.cpp(337) : error C2065: 'lea' : identifier not declared

Comment: You either have something wrongly using `_INTSIZEOF` in `Errores.cpp` or you have your project incorrectly configured for x64.  Aside from that, inline assembly is not supported in MSVC when building for 64-bit targets, so you'll have to fix that, too.  Post some of the code around line 337 so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that ur compiler does not originally supported this MACRO, so u might try to add these in the front of ur code:
`#define _INTSIZEOF(n)  ((sizeof(n)+sizeof(int)-1)&~(sizeof(int) - 1) )`

Comment: Illegal; `_I` is a prefix reserved for the compiler. Not that it's necessary anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Right. The problem was that I use "va_start" in my routine and more specifically a solution given by "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4181/Variable-Argument-Functions?msg=4204968#xx4204968xx" solution that works perfectly in Win32, but not on x64 does that not allow use __ asm.
 example:

```
# define va_start (ap, v) {int var = _INTSIZEOF (v); __ asm read eax, v add eax __ asm, __ asm mov var ap, eax}

 float add (float &x, ...) {

 va_list list;
 va_start (list, x);

 float result = 0;

 for (;;)
 {
 float p = (float) va_arg (list, double);
 if (p == 0)
 break;
 result + = p;

 }
 va_end (list);
 return result;

 }

 int main () {

 float hh = 2.1;
 cout << "Result is" << add (/ * 2.1 * / hh, 4.3,6.8);
 return 0;

 }
```

Now I have the problem that __ asm does not work on x64, but I can to solve it if I remove "&" like:
 "float add (float x, ...) {"